# How to send email to outlook without backend

Tags: reactjs, email, outlook, smtp

I have a simple React application and I would like to create a form that sends an email to a specific Outlook adress without having to add my own backend.

I first looked at email.js, a library that works fine for Gmail but not for Outlook in my case. When I try to set up the correct Email, I get:

412Hotmail: Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [MW4PR04CA0143.namprd04.prod.outlook.com]

This leads into a maze of powershell commands that, for reasons that are hard to summarize, were very difficult to follow through and actually make it work.

I then tried using https://www.smtpjs.com/, but I can't make it work with React. The following code:

```
Email.send({
            Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
            Username : "username",
            Password : "password",
            To : 'email@email.com',
            From : "you@isp.com",
            Subject : "This is the subject",
            Body : "And this is the body"
        }).then(
          message => alert(message)
        );
```

gives the error that "Email is not defined", it doesn't matter where I insert my script tag, in my component or in index.html. I also tried

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"
```

inside the component, still does not work.

The only solution that actually works so far is https://formspree.io/, but it is a sub-par solution where the sender is redirected to a Formspree page.

I have a very vague understanding of SMTP, so perhaps I am making some rookie mistake with smtp.js.
Grateful for any help.

Comment: The error message is telling you that Exchange is configured to reject the action you are trying to perform. The Powershell commands you are alluding to are probably telling the site admin how to change this, but won't help you if you are not an admin.

Comment: Sending _to_ Outlook via Gmail should still work fine; is there a particular reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: I used Powershell as admin, that was not the problem. 

"Sending to Outlook via Gmail" - do you mean for the Email.js solution, that I should somehow add a Gmail address as a "middleman" between the submitted form and the Outlook address? Not sure I understand.

Comment: When you send email to outlook.com you just need to be able to connect to your ISP's mail server, and they will take it from there. You can do the same with Gmail if you have an account there. The "host" field in your configuration is responsible for this; which email address you are allowed to use on that server can vary, but in many cases you can put anything you like.

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now, the problem is I can't even get there because of the error "Email is not defined".

Comment: Again, why did you abandon sending via Gmail if that was working for you?

Comment: The website I am building was suppose to send a mail from the contact form to a particular Outlook address. But I am abandoning the attempt now - I will send to a Gmail address instead.

Comment: Again, if you have a Gmail account, you can perfectly well connect to Gmail and send email _to_ any address, including Outlook.